# Adding column that shows the number of parts of features

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, multipart

I want to create a new field in my attribute table that shows of how many parts each feature exists (QGIS). I know how to make a new field and where I can find the Field Calculator. I do not know the command to calculate the amount of parts yet however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use  `num_geometries( $geometry)`.

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I needed! makes my work a lot easier!